# Rebranding announcement timing

Tags: client-relations, branding, business, marketing, communication

I've been searching all over the web about the Rebranding Announcement strategy and was not able to get to a solid conclusion about whether or not to make the Rebranding announcement before the rebranding itself.

My question is, is it beneficial or not at all recommended to make a rebranding announcement before it is effective. I have a rebranding within a month and not sure if to announce it as a "will happen" or announce it only "when it happens".

Thanks in advance for any insights in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is rather marketing decision than graphic design.  And you won't get a solid conclusion.
Some companies might want to announce rebranding. Allowing customer to adjust to change, this assume that customers use is so periodicall that the gap beetwen must be filled with remainder (and it's not the only reason).
Some companies might want to make an event out of rebranding assuming wider brand recognition. This assume that rebranding is just another occasion to mark product presence on the market (and it's not the only reason).
Some companies might not want to announce the rebranding at all. This assume that the rebranding must differentiate the "new" with "old" as a two totally separete things.

Comment: Thanks for the insight SZCZERZO KŁY. Its sure a tricky question and as you say, probably not a graphic design question (my fault), but we are most of the times involved in these processes and though the question here. Will have to make a decision based on balance of the expected rebranding goals. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Most rebranding is just shown when it happens.

Unless clients have a specific interest in this information and need to somehow participate in the process, this should not be of interest to clients before it happens.

However, there might be specific business reasons for shareholders and people involved in running the company in having this announced *internally*, as a rebranding can sometimes have in-house effects on the actual management structure, ownership, etc.

Comment: Thanks Lucian, your answer goes more towards to what I believe should be the correct way to do it. I agree with the internal communication and letting the external (public) communication to when it happens. Thanks for your insight.